# Desktop background will not load after performing aticonfig --adapter=all --ovt=opengl

Tags: ati, xorg, radeon

I am trying to get Eagle to work on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I run Eagle and open a schematic the display is not refreshing/redrawing correctly. One solution that I found was to install the flgrx drivers and do the aticonfig command to use opengl... So I did and rebooted. Now when I turn on my laptop I get all the way to the login screen, login, and then nothing happens, it just goes to the background image with no icons or anything... I tried deleting and copying the original xorg.conf file and no results... What do I do other than reinstalling Ubuntu? is there anyway to force the original driver?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` solve it? You would need to `sudo shutdown -r now` afterwards (reboot).

Comment: That did not fix it, It said that it was already up to date

Answer (score 0):

Sorry dude my first try was wrong. I had it and then removed it again. Now I have the correct settings again.

This helped me:

http://www.securethelock.com/2014/04/20/installing-configuring-amdati-drivers-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

try this here. I just did it myself 1 h ago. I dont have the right drivers right now but i can use my system.

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```